# Return AuthenticateResult.Fail result during AddOAuth OnCreatingTicket

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core

I want to cause oAuth to fail during the OnCreatingTicket event.  I can call .Fail but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Is it too late in the workflow?  Am I missing some additional code to actually process the failure?

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddCookie().AddOAuth("schemename", SetOAuthOptions);

private void SetOAuthOptions(OAuthOptions options)
{
    options.ClientId = ...;
    options.ClientSecret = ...;
    options.CallbackPath = ...;
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = ...;
    options.TokenEndpoint = ...;
    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = async context => await AddIdentityClaimsAsync(context),
        OnTicketReceived = ...
    };
}

private async Task AddIdentityClaimsAsync(OAuthCreatingTicketContext context)
{
    ...
    if(noAccess)
        context.Fail("Sorry, you don't have access to the product.");
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out by any chance? I am in a similar situation, I need to perform additional validation (API call) once I have an access token from external provider.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the OAuthCreatingTicketContext.Fail doesn't end up affecting the HandleRequestResult that is ultimately returned by the authentication call.  What I ended up having to do was to throw a known exception from the OnCreatingTicket handler, override OAuthHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync to catch it and from there call HandleRequestResult.Fail with the exception.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie().AddOAuth("schemename", SetOAuthOptions);

private void SetOAuthOptions(OAuthOptions options)
{
    options.ClientId = ...;
    options.ClientSecret = ...;
    options.CallbackPath = ...;
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = ...;
    options.TokenEndpoint = ...;
    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = async context => await AddIdentityClaimsAsync(context),
        OnTicketReceived = ...
    };
}

private async Task AddIdentityClaimsAsync(OAuthCreatingTicketContext context)
{
    ...
    if(noAccess)
        throw new MyCustomException("Sorry, you don't have access to the product.");
}

// In OAuthHandler<T>
protected override async Task<HandleRequestResult> HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
{    
    try
    {
        return await base.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync();
    }
    catch (MyCustomException e)
    {
        return HandleRequestResult.Fail(e);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can you tell me how you override the default `OAuthHandler<T>`? I am trying to do the same, but I can't figure it out... :\

Comment: I am using OpenIdConnect though, so things might be a bit more complex....

Comment: @user2173353 It's been a long while, but you might be able to inherit from OpenIdConnectHandler and override the HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync method, then do something like below to register it:

services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<OpenIdConnectHandler, CustomOpenIdConnectHandler>());

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

In startup, after AddOAuth:

`.AddScheme<OAuthOptions, BearerAuthHandler>(BearerAuthHandler.DefaultSchemeName, ...);`

This goes in your controller:

`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = BearerAuthHandler.DefaultSchemeName)]`

This is the scheme class: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hujDtz